# Different structures of wordpress get posts

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

**New Edit**
How to select posts where 'post_meta' has one of `$defaults` key !

```
$defaults = array(
    'artist_139' = 139,
    'artist_125' = 125,
    'artist_165' = 165,
    'artist_189' = 189,
    'artist_149' = 149,
);
$followingposts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'songs',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'myfield',
            'value' => $defaults,
            'compare'   => 'IN'
        )
    ),
));
```

**And** (get_field('myfield') returns:)

```
 get_field('myfield') = array(
        'artist_139' = 139,
        'artist_165' = 165,
    );
```

Comment: Pretty Unclear What you want to achieve over here, or what you want to depict over here

Comment: I think you should try to reformulate the question, I didn't understand too what you're asking. And as an additional note, please use code and quote markup in a proper way: code is inside the code markup, and quote markup is only for... quotes.

Comment: songs has checkbox to select arists, now I want to select songs where one  of the  `$arists key` is in array(132,127,129,157,164),

Comment: cant you help me ? :(

Comment: Please give some edit to your question, try to reformulate with some more informations. It's still pretty unclear what you ask.

Comment: The post has been edited !

Comment: @danialdezfooli No need to spam comments for help, we're not at you disposal. And to transform your array to a valid `meta_query` value, querying with the key of your `$defaults` array, try `array_flip($defaults)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89307/discussion-between-danial-dezfooli-and-vard).